# write a conditional based on params change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, memoization

I'm attempting to utilize memoization to speed up some database queries and I've run into a snag with the date params set by a user.

```
def self.stats_by_user_id(start_date, end_date)
  @stats_by_user_id ||= BingRecord.select([:user_id, :stats])
                                .where(date: start_date..end_date)
                                .where(user_id: ["9","22"])
                                .group_by(&:user_id)
end

def self.get_bing_result(user_id, start_date, end_date)
  a = stats_by_user_id(start_date, end_date)[user_id]

  b = a.map(&:stats)

 result = b.reduce({}) do |o, hash|
   o.merge(hash) { |_, v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) { |_, vv1, vv2| vv1 + vv2 } }
 end
end
```

A user will pass `start_date` and `end_date` via params.  My problem is, once @stats_by_user_id is set once with those params, any subsequent date change passing new params will be ignored.

I'd like to set a condition that checks for params to have been changed but I can't seem to figure out how to check for that.  Is there a way to check if params has been updated so I can reassign the value to @stats_by_user_id?

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it, but something like this:

```
def self.stats_by_user_id(start_date, end_date)
  @cache ||= {}

  @cache.fetch([start_date, end_date]) do
    @cache[[start_date, end_date]] = BingRecord.select([:user_id, :stats])
                                               .where(date: start_date..end_date)
                                               .where(user_id: ['9', '22'])
                                               .group_by(&:user_id)
  end
end
```